# Can django restframework generics.ListCreateAPIView deal with one-to-one field?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model `UserProfile` which has a OneToOneField related to Django User model
And I have `UserProfileList` in views.py

```
class UserProfileList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

I want to post data to `UserProfileList`
The format like :

```
{   "username":"username",
    "email":"email@email",
    "password":"password",
    "secret_id":1
}
```

('username','email','password' is from `User` model
secret_id is from `UserProfile` )

and it can save data both in `User` and `UserProfile` table
Is it posibble??

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    secret_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import UserProfileSerializer, UserSerializer
from account.models import UserProfile

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserProfileList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

class UserProfileDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

serializer.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from account.models import UserProfile


    class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
            fields = ('user','secret_id')

    class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username','email','password')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve this.

In order to have access to the `username`, `email` and `password` fields from within the `UserProfileSerializer`, you need to define these fields on it, otherwise, the serializer's validation will throw out fields that are not defined on the serializer:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperLinkedModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        ...
```

Notice that the explicitly defined fields are `write_only`, so that on read they won't show up.

The above code will assure you that these fields won't be eliminated from `validated_attrs` in your serializer's `.create()` and `.update()` methods.

After this you have 2 options

## Option #1

You need to overwrite the `.create()` method of your `UserProfileSerializer` in order to create your `User` model besides the `UserProfile` model.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperLinkedModelSerializer):
    # above definitions

    def create(self, validated_attrs):
        # now you have here the email, username and password arguments 
        email = validated_attrs.pop('email', None)
        username = validated_attrs.pop('username', None)
        password = validated_attrs.pop('password', None)

        # your creation logic here
        user = User.objects.create(...)
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, ...)
```

## Option #2

You can handle the creation of `UserProfile` from within the `User` creation process (see [handling saving related instances in model manager classes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#handling-saving-related-instances-in-model-manager-classes)). For this you need to define a custom `UserManager` class.

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
...

def create(self, username, email, secret_id=None):
    user = User(username=username, email=email)
    user.save()
    user_profile = UserProfile(
        user=user,
        secret_id=secret_id
    )
    user_profile.save()
    return user
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I got it!!